# Hermitian Projections on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A projection on a complex Banach space $X$ is said to hermitian if its numerical range is real.

Does anyone know an example of an hermitian projection on $C[0,1]_{\mathbb C}=C[0,1]\oplus i C[0,1]$?

Comment: Is the numerical range of an operator $\frac{\int \bar f A f}{\int \bar f f}$?

Comment: No, it isn't. I follow the definition in the Duncan and Bonsall's book. But I am not sure whether the definitions coincide.

Comment: Can you give the definition?

Comment: If $X$ is a normed linear space and $S(X)$ its unit sphere, $X'$ its dual space and $\Pi= \{(x,f)\in S(X)\times S(X') \ | \ f(x)=1 \},$ then for an operator $T$ on $X$, the numerical range $V(T)$ is defined by $V(T)=\{f(Tx) \ | \ (x,f)\in \Pi\}.$